# Как сделать ресурс на ASP.NET правильно?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Стоит такая задача, хочу через Веб приложение реализовать выгрузку всех IP - адресов в нашей локальной сети в таблицу. Я в принципе смог это сделать, но при открытии страницы уходит очень много времени, что и понятно. Вот пример, как я это делаю.

```
List<string> host = new List<string>();
for (int i = 10; i <= 13; i++)
{
    string ips = "192.168.4." + i;
    try
    {
        host.Add(Dns.GetHostEntry(ips).HostName);
    }
    catch
    {
        host.Add("Unknown host");
        continue;
    }
}
ReapeterContacts.DataSource = host;
ReapeterContacts.DataBind();
```

По - какой мне схеме действовать, сперва собрать информацию в базу и отображать базу пользователю? Но минус в том, что адреса могут меняться и актуальную инфу нужно запрашивать к примеру раз день. Вот я не знаю как это реализуется!?  Это к примеру должна быть служба на сервере IIS? Каким образом мне опрашивать локалку с периодичностью раз день и выводить эту информацию пользователю? Я учу сишарп с нуля и знания у меня не большие. Спасибо!

Comment: А почему бы не обновлять информацию время от времени без запроса пользователя, а по запросу отдавать последнюю полностью обновлённую информацию? Пускай сервер в фоне собирает, что нужно.

Comment: В ASP.NET если запросов нет, то приложение выгружается из памяти.

Comment: Логично. Получается я должен на серваке реализовать приложение,которое будет это делать и выгружать все в базу и потом с помощью Asp отображать пользователю? Ну что мне нуджно сделать на серваке ? Службу ? Или что?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую вам для начала присмотреться к `OutputCache`. Этот механизм позволит довольно просто и быстро решить вашу проблему. Он доступен как в [`Web Forms`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49704/ASP-NET-Page-Output-Cache), так и в [`MVC`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs).

Фактически, после первой проверки IP адресов будет происходить кэширование вернутого пользователю контента (`html`-разметки). С последующими запросами пользлователей к странице ее содержимое будет возвращаться из кэша.

Comment: получается один раз грузим долго, а потом быстро?

Comment: Именно так. Первый раз грузится долго, а после отображание страницы помещается в кэш и в дальнейшем берется из него. Время кэширования настраивается.